# pdo display none with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have some code here
and i don't know why it doesn't display anything

```
function konek() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=payroll;port=3306', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}

$pdo = konek();
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM karyawan WHERE noreg LIKE '%:keyword%' OR nama LIKE '%:keyword%' ORDER BY noreg ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$daftar = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($daftar as $kar) {

    echo '<li>'.$kar['noreg'].'||'.$kar['nama'].'</li>';
}
?>
```

is something wrong with my code?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: add a try/catch(PDOException) surrounding your call konek()

Comment: @Monty theres no error warning , it just display none

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi , there no error too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the way you're using your prepared statement to include the %% in the bindParam method, instead of the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM karyawan WHERE noreg LIKE :keyword OR nama LIKE :keyword ORDER BY noreg ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
```

then

```
$query->bindParam(':keyword', '%'.$keyword.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the `%` signs in the `bindParam`, not in the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM karyawan WHERE noreg LIKE :keyword OR nama LIKE :keyword ORDER BY noreg ASC LIMIT :start, :end";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', '%'.$keyword.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':start', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':end', 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: i think $query->bindParam(':keyword', '%'.$keyword.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR); is enough, i dont need :start and :end

Comment: Yes!! but you can bind also your limits